# Html writing empty line when variable is empty

Tags: html, asp.net, razor

This is in razor but the question is the same:

```
div class="description">@Server.UrlDecode(Model.Text1)</div>
div class="description">@Server.UrlDecode(Model.Text2)</div>
```

If one on my variable is empty it will print an empty line, I want it to not print an empty line in that case, how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

just check that empty or not using `if` condition

```
@if (Model.Text1)
{
  <div class="description">@Server.UrlDecode(Model.Text1)</div>
}
@if (Model.Text2)
{
  <div class="description">@Server.UrlDecode(Model.Text2)</div>
}
```